# android write to disk unreliable - written file.length !=expected.length

Tags: java, android, file-io, filesystems

I have a write method that will write a `byte[]` to disk. On very few devices I'm running into some strange problems where the written `file.length() != byte[].length` after a successful write operation.

### Code and Problem

The code to write a file to disk

```
private static boolean writeByteFile(File file, byte[] byteData) throws IOException {
    if (!file.exists()) {
        boolean fileCreated = file.createNewFile();
        if (!fileCreated) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
    bos.write(byteData);
    bos.flush();
    fos.getFD().sync(); // sync to disk as recommended: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/12/saving-data-safely.html
    fos.close();


    if (file.length() != byteData.length) {
        final byte[] originalMD5Hash = md.digest(byteData);

        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

        while(bis.read(buffer) > -1) {
            md.update(buffer);
        }
        is.close();

        final byte[] writtenFileMD5Hash = md.digest();

        if(!Arrays.equals(originalMD5Hash, writtenFileMD5Hash)) {
            String message = String.format(
                    "After an fsync, the file's length is not equal to the number of bytes we wrote!\npath=%s, expected=%d, actual=%d.  >>  " +
                    "Original MD5 Hash: %s, written file MD5 hash: %s",
                    file.getAbsolutePath(), byteData.length, file.length(),
                    digestToHex(originalMD5Hash), digestToHex(writtenFileMD5Hash));
            throw new GiantWtfException(message);
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

I'm running into the `if-statement` where I compare file length on a few devices.
One example output:

`After an fsync, the file's length is not equal to the number of bytes we wrote! path=/mnt/sdcard/.folder/filename, expected=233510, actual=229376 >> Original MD5 Hash: f1d298c0484672c52d9c26d04a3a21dc, written file MD5 hash: ab30660bd2b476d9551c15b340207a8a`

I currently see this problem on 5 devices as I'm slowly rolling out the code. Some device data:

### Question

Is there anything else I can do or improve?

### More stats and observations

**Current system version**

- 2.3.5
- 2.3.6

**Model**

- N860 (LG)
- GT-I9100G (Samsung)
- GT-S5300 (Samsung)
- GT-S7500 (Samsung)
- LG-VS410PP (LG)

**Other stats**

In the general crash analytics (from Crittercism) there is always more then enough free disk space at the time the problem happens. Still some (not all) of the devices have thrown IOExceptions around `no free disk space` at a different point in time.

As always I've never been able to reproduce that problem on any test phone I have.

**Assumptions / Observations:**

Generally I would expect a IOException when the disk is full. Still all the exceptions that I catch have less bytes written then they should have.

Interestingly enough all the number of bytes that actually have been written to disk are a multiple of `2^15`.

**EDIT:**
I added a MD5 check sum validation that also fails and simplified the example code a little for better readability. It still fails in the wild with different MD5 hashes.

Comment: Filesizes will differ based on the block size of the partitions. Are you sure the files written are not the same as the originals, using checksums?

Comment: I haven't. But how can the file size be smaller then the original number of bytes I want to write when I'm not compressing it?

Comment: If the block sizes differ, the "file size on disk" can be smaller on one partition. If you're just confirming the file transferred intact, a checksum (a la `md5sum`) will be far more reliable; consider the case that your written file is the same size as the source file, but the written data is corrupted.

Comment: I agree that the sum would be safer for corrupted data after write for the price of more time. I'll look into how long that will take to compute. however I'm not sure if I understand how the written file can be smaller. I'm just missing bytes when they are not there?

Comment: I understand java `file.length` from the android docs with the return value being `the number of bytes in this file.` as the logical file size, not the actual representation on disk.

Comment: ^^ Ok, then I'm not sure what could be going on. Good luck with checksumming, that doesn't typically take too long on smaller files.

Answer (score 0):

philipp, `file.length()` is the file size as reported by the OS. It might be the space the file takes up on disk or the number of bytes in the file.

If the number returned is size on disk, it is related to the number of clusters that hold the file. For example NTFS generally uses 4KB clusters. If you save a text document with 3 ascii encoded characters in on an NTFS formatted volume, the size of the file is 3 bytes, the size of the file on disk is 4096 bytes. On NTFS with a 4KB cluster all files are a multiple of 4096 bytes on disk. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_cluster for more.

If the number returned is the length of the file in bytes (from the underlying file-system's meta-data) then you should have an exact match to how many bytes you wrote, though I wouldn't bet my life on it.

Android uses YAFFS or EXT4, if that helps at all.

I strongly agree with admdrew, use a hash. MD5 would work great. SHA or even CRC should work fine for this task. As you write bytes to the disk, feed the stream to your hash algorithm as well. Once the file is written, read it back and feed that to your hasher. Compare the results. **If you want to be sure the data is clean, file size is not enough.**

Comment: file.length() returns the length of the content of the file according to Java API spec. Never the less I added a MD5 hash check and it also fails.